# How can upload photos via graph api but when the photos it outside the server?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to upload some photos to Facebook via graph api but the photos are not in the same server, It is possible?

Comment: You will need to download those photos to your server first, and then upload them.

Comment: i understand @jlb but the customer cannot give me that access.

Comment: @MrSanders I read your comment after posting my answer below.  You do not have access to the images via HTTP (browser) or FTP/SCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but requires an intermediate step (as @jlb mentions) of storing a local copy.  You simply need the URL(s) for the image(s) you want to pull and appropriate permissions on Facebook.  Try this:

```
function pushImageToFacebook( $url_of_image , $fb_user_id , $fb_access_token )
{
  // Creates a new image file in the local directory and gets
  // ...a file handle for it.  MAKE SURE that you are able to
  // ...write to and read from the local directory or this 
  // ...will fail due to permissions.
  $fh = fopen( $filename = 'image' . microtime() , 'w' );
  // Writes the image data to the local file
  fwrite( $fh , file_get_contents( $url_of_image ) );
  // Closes the file handle
  fclose( $fh );

  // Sets the message argument
  $args = array( 'message' => 'Photo Uploaded Using cURL' );
  // Sets the filename argument
  $args[basename($filename)] = '@' . realpath($filename);
  // Initializes a cURL session and gets a cURL handle
  $ch = curl_init();
  // This is your Facebook Graph API URL
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_user_id}/photos?access_token={$fb_access_token}";
  // Set all of your cURL session options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
  // Fire the cURL and grab the return data (Facebook image ID)
  $buffer = curl_exec($ch);

  // OPTIONAL : Display the Facebook image ID
  print_r( json_decode( $buffer , true ) );

  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i execute a similar process but the customer (coca-cola i supposed by security concerns) have a really complicate server process to write files, and i need to find any way to upload that photos without downloading. (if there is another way! :( )

Comment: Are the images you are supposed to push to Facebook already on the customer's server, or are you setting something up so that future images will be pushed to Facebook?  Without having access to the images, it is impossible to get them onto Facebook with or without the Graph API.  Can you please provide more details about the workflow here?  Where is your code going to reside?  On the same server as the images?

Comment: the images are outside the primary server, i understand that the photos needs to be in the same server that api makes the upload and i did that, but the customer don't let me download the photos in the same server then i'm trying to found some other way to upload that photos without download them. But it seems that it is imposible. Facebook don't let upload photos via url.
Workflow: server (where resides FB api key)->request download photos from outside-server(in this step customer says DON'T you need to find out another way)->once download them->Facebook upload (server where resides FB api).

Comment: @MrSanders So we definitely understand each other about the workflow.  What confuses me is this: why does the customer object to the images temporarily stopping on the server doing the FB uploads?  Obviously the images aren't proprietary or sensitive, because they're being uploaded to a public site (Facebook).  Is the customer concerned about bandwidth?  Will the customer let you place your code directly on the outside-server(with the images)?

Comment: according to the customer it is about distributed charges, and about some http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network  that we need to request to do that.

Comment: I would consider it "acceptable" to require the customer provide you access to the files you're to work with.  You could probably use symbolic links to avoid getting into the details of their SAN, but this is a pretty standard task.  After all, how are you supposed to upload an image you can't find?  This is sort of like asking the customer for the file path to the images they want you to upload and being told that you can't have that information.  Analogy: a customer asks you to wash their car, but won't tell you where it is; if you can't find it, how are you supposed to work with/on it?

Comment: finally gains access :), the customer allows to write in the server. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the customer is not thinking that you will post a link to photos that exist on their server to FB so that each view would generate traffic on their site.. If the images have no IP concern, then I am thinking they are concerned that other external parties would be following a URL to their internal server..

Alternatively, have the customer email you the photos, then poll the INBOX with a cron script, then download from the mailbox and upload to FB on receipt. You need to address security concerns, like someone finding the email addr and emailing photos that should not be put on FB..